# NTFS partitions hidden under EXT4 file system / partition...want to recover files from NTFS

Tags: filesystem, ntfs, data-recovery, partitioning

I am new to ubuntu, but very impressed with the system.
so one day i tried installing ubuntu 10.10 along with windows in dual boot first place it didnt get installed properly and during second attempt i could do it right but oh...i lost my windows 7 ,

here is my problem and what i have done till now.

1. i have hdd installed with ubuntu same disk have windows partitions and i need to extract data from those ...very very important
2. i tried to access the same from ubuntu ...can not access it,
   3.reinstalled the windows 7 , hdd is not detected
   4.during installation ubuntu gone , so reintalled
3. scan in ubuntu says hdd is fine and DiskInternals linux reader actual show the NTFS partitions , recovery tool not able to get any data out.

   , please help i need data from these partitions...please

I feel that i have put ext4 partition on ntfs filesystem...and now not able to access it

Comment: sorry I don't understand your numbers...

Comment: Boot from an Ubuntu live CD, open a terminal and run: sudo fdisk -l , post the result from the command.

Comment: Normally when installing Windows, it removes grub, the bootloader and installs its own. Windows bootloader doesn't detect other OS's so most likely Ubuntu wasn't deleted unless you installed it on the same partition. Also Filesystem's "go inside" partitions, 1 (non-virtual) filesystem per partition.

Comment: In step 2 where you said you reinstalled windows 7, this probably reformatted the NTFS partition, and wiped out your data, quoted from, http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-7/514412-windows-7-installation-guide-tutorial.html "Make sure the drive don't have any important data or the Windows 7 installation will wipe-out the contents of that partition."

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

[I wish I had reputation to comment...]

You did not specify if you overwrote the old NTFS partition or created a new partition.  I am hoping you installed you created a new partition on the disk.  (If you overwrote it, there is some hope, but not much hope.)

First thing to do is to stop booting the hard disk on the machine!  You don't want any further chances to overwrite data.

Next,  Go to another machine, and download a copy of the System Rescue CD (at the link below), and then read this section on recovering a non-booting windows installation: http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_Backup_data_from_an_unbootable_windows_computer.

Good Luck.